# need help understanding the "when" function used in Mockito (for Flutter)

Tags: flutter, mockito

im learning using Mockito in a Flutter app.

my goal here, is to have a single unit test that confirms that the desired class ("User") is returned from a mocked API call.

i've followed docs and some examples and have a working test. HOWEVER - my issue is I don't understand the purpose of `when(..` ? looking at the code it seems to me like this is all just a self fulfilling prophesy since the `when(..` call is hardcoded to return a `User` class object.

So, ermmm, wouldn't this test ALWAYS pass ?

i know i am definitely misunderstanding something here and would appreciate someone clarifying for me? (so then i can have a "duh" moment ;-)

**example_test.dart**

```
class MockAuthService extends Mock implements IAuthenticationService {}
class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {

  setUpAll(() {});

  test('fetchUser returns a valid User object', () async {
    final client = MockClient();
    var mockAuthService = MockAuthService();

    when(mockAuthService.fetchUser(client)).thenAnswer((_) async => User(title: "Fred"));**
    (====> what exactly is this "when" line of code doing ? <====)

    var result = await mockAuthService.fetchUser(client);

    expect(await mockAuthService.fetchUser(client), isNotNull);
    expect(result.title, "Fred");
  });
}
```

**model**

```
class User {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  User({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      body: json['body'],
    );
  }
}
```

**authentication_service.dart**

this is the function i want to test:

```
Future<User> fetchUser(http.Client client) async {
    final response =
    await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create a User object');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Normally, you mock an object with `when` to get a stable result from **provider** (`MockAuthService`). You need to test *the object* who used the **provider**, which output might be unstable, so mock it with `when` to get that output to get *the object* with full controll.

Comment: Oh now I see - so basically the *when* is really part of the setup. And you would use that setup, to help test something else that *relied upon* what you had defined in the when statement.

Comment: Absolutely, you got It :)